# is there a way to have 2 dates under a customer's name in Microsoft access

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm an intern student at a company that does both wiring and aircon services. The job that they gave me was to make a database for them. I don't have any experience in anything related to databases.

So, I started to look up videos and stuff to at least learn a bit about databases and made something that works and I made it after 1.5 months of learning.

in the database that I created,

I have 1 table (CustomerDetailsT):

CustomerID (pk)

CustomerName

PhoneNumber

Address

Aircond    (type and model of ac,ex: WM daikin 1.0HP)

AcDetails  (what has been done for the ac.)

Others (yes/no)     (Wiring, installing a fan and so on)

WhatHasBeenDone    (shows what has been done for others)

Then 3 queries (CustomerOthersDetailsQ, CustomerAcDetailsQ, CustomerDetailsQ).**CustomerAcDetailsQ** has *CustomerName, PhoneNumber, Address, Aircond* and *AcDetails*. **CustomerOthersDetailsQ** has *CustomerName, PhoneNumber, Address, Others,* and *WhatHasBeenDone*.**CustomerDetailsQ** has *CustomerID, CustomerName, PhoneNumber* and *Address*

And 1 form with 3 subforms.
it's a search form, which would search for customers as we're typing in their name/phone number and it will show what has been done for the customer.

With this, I have created what the company wants, but now they want to add dates. Dates which would show when we have done something for a customer. Dates for Aircond and the Others stuff.

I've tried with what I know and it didn't work. tried searching it on youtube and google, but still couldn't find it.

how can I go about doing this?. I have tried having separate tables for each service, but it became a hassle when I wanted to create a new customer. . I hope I could some help, I could send pictures if someone needs them.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtrmC.png [The Customer search form] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Y9d.png [example of a customer that has ac installation] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsGL5.png [example of a customer that has both ac and wiring done]

Comment: Have a table for ServicesGiven, fields like: SvsDate, SvsCode, CustID, Comments. Your question is not really appropriate for SO as it is too broad, responses would be opinions, there is no code to analyze.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so where should i post my question?...should it be in the access forum?

Comment: A discussion forum would likely be more appropriate than SO Q&A model. AccessForums.net is one.

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging the question is too broad, here is some guidance.  One of the nice things about Access is that each database is a single file.  First protect your work by finding that file and make   two copies.  Make a backup and a play around version.  Only mess with the play around version.
Your question indicates you are still learning Table Normalization and 1 to many relationships.  Both of these topics are general to all databases, so you don't have to restrict yourself to just Access when looking for guides and Youtube videos.
Part of normalization is putting separate entities into their own tables.  Also, in Access there is a big payoff for using the Relationship Tool, so here is a rather lame example of normalization:

[image]

Make sure to select the checkboxes when setting up relationships.
WhatHasbeenDone should also have WhatHasbeenDoneDate.  I've wrapped AC and Other as Unit because later it will be easier than having two WhatHasBeenDone tables(AC)(Other).

Now imagine someone taking the customer request call.  They just want to see a form to enter the customer details, request, unit-type, etc.  They don't want to see those tables.  Even with training entering data in the tables is error prone.  The person fulfilling the request just wants to enter what they did and when.  That's how you start to figure out what your final Data entry forms will look like.

Since we normalized the tables and used the relationships tool, the payoff is Access can give us an assortment of working starter forms.  Select Each Table and then hit Create and then hit Form.  Choose your Favorites and start playing around from there.  While playing, keep in mind that Access will not let you add an item on the many side of a relationship unless there is an item on the 1 side.
For example I selected the customers table and hit create form:

[image]

Access uses a concept of form and subform based on separate but related tables.  So, to get a form that shows what has been done for each customer I created a form for the What has been done table, and dragged it onto the customers form:

[image]

Unless an ID is also being used as a part number or something there is probably no reason for the person entering data to see it.  So I removed the texboxes bound to ID's.  Except for UnitTypeID, where I replaced the textbox with a combobox that displays the userfriendly UnitDescription.  The ID's are still part of the form recordsources, Access is still adding new IDs and using those IDs to put the appropriate data in the right tables.

[image]

Oh, didn't we need dates (went back and added a date to the table, and adjusted the subform accordingly).  Also changed the subform format from single record to continuous records to show multiple dates:

[image]

In conclusion and in my opinion your final forms will use VBA behind the scenes to insert data from the forms into the tables.  This is because either you will want to rapidly insert multiple records or How the end users think about the data will not match the default forms and subforms approach Access depends upon to figure out how to insert the data.  However, the default approach is fast and I always use it for version 1 of my Access Databases.

P.S.  For simplicity I avoided including any Many to Many relationships

Comment: is there a way where I could send you the file so you could have a look around..?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't permit the attaching of files.  Give my directions a try and play around.  Your understanding will improve.

Comment: I did follow your directions, yet I'm still lost.the thing with me is, I kinda understand what normalization is (having something in common so that other tables could interact with and keeping the tables clean). but what I lack is applying it to the tables. even if I did do it, I don't know how to sync the data when I create a new customer because it just does not sync. either that or I cant add new customers at all.

Comment: I suggest simplifying the problem to one table.  then hit create - form and let access auto build the form.  Study how the autogenerated form inserts and removes data from the table when you play with it.  Then extend to a one 1 to many relationship between two tables.  review the access relationship tool on the internet and make sure to hook up the 1 to many relationship properly between a primary key and a foreign key.  Then auto generate forms from both tables.  If you have done it right, access will properly  enter data in the tables again.